# Do I have to visit the Pakistani embassy in person to get an Iranian visa?

Tags: visas, iran

I'm an American planning on going on a tour to Iran this summer. The process for getting a visa to Iran involves applying to the Iranian foreign ministry, and, upon getting conditional approval, taking your passport to the Pakistani embassy in Washington, D.C. to get the actual visa. Do I have to visit the Pakistani embassy in person? I don't live in D.C., so it would be a flight for me to visit the embassy, which of course I would like to avoid. I'd like to send my passport to a friend who lives in D.C. and have them drop it off for me. Would that be possible?

Comment: Be aware that for a couple of months, US citizens were denied visas (https://www.intrepidtravel.com/adventures/travel-iran-usa-citizens/) - worth keeping an eye on the news.

Comment: @bosquito It’s likely you’ll need to provide biometrics, so I’d say the answer is you’ll need to go in person.

Comment: @Traveller a lot of biometrics for other countries visa are done at local USCIS centres.

Comment: @BritishSam while you're correct, I strongly doubt Iran will be using USCIS centers for biometrics.

Comment: @crayarikar worth checking still, but yeah i doubt they want to share data with each other.

Answer (score 2):

The process is done through the post, following the steps outlined by the [Embassy of Pakistan Interests Section of the Islamic Republic of Iran](http://www.daftar.org/forms/visas/601.pdf) in Washington DC. After completing the application form directly with the [Iran's Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://e_visa.mfa.ir/en/), you'll receive a confirmed (Visa Application Submission Notice) which you print, and send to the Embassy in Washington.

Side note: there is no walk-in service, as this embassy handles applications for all of North America. For safety, the package can be sent by FedEx; the $40 postal fee that you'll be charged covers it to be returned to you via FedEx.